# Generate Django "unique_together" key with "id" field

Tags: python, django

Here is the model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s from %s" % (self.id, self.area)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("id", "area"),)
```

I am trying to generate a unique key using Django's built-in `Id` functionality without making `Id` as a primary key.

Possible?

Comment: stepping back for a moment... it's a bit of an odd model if the `id` is not unique, it raises the question of what is the 'meaning' of the `id` field?  either way, `unique_together` does what you need, but you can only have a single primary key field (can't do composite keys in Django yet, but see here for further info and 3rd party hacks https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys)

Comment: I can rename `Id` to `user_id`. This will solve the issue. `User.user_id` is a bit weird naming convention than `User.id`.

Comment: I am trying to modify the default behavior of `Id`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can have a primary key based on multiple column (cf. django doc : https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys).

Only unique_together will still work.

In case what you want is an auto incremented field which is not a primary key :

> AutoField¶
>
> class AutoField(**options)¶ An IntegerField that automatically
>   increments according to available IDs. You usually won’t need to use
>   this directly; a primary key field will automatically be added to your
>   model if you don’t specify otherwise. See Automatic primary key
>   fields.

Comment: Well, `unique_together` works fine for me. I just want to set `primary_key=False` to Django's default `Id` field. Possible?

Comment: You could add an AutoField which is a auto-incremented integer to achieve what you want I think. If you do not want id as primary key to be created by django, making an other field primary key should work (your model need a unique column as primary key).

Comment: Let me write in detail. I don't know why I can't edit my question. I am writing it here anyway.

Consider `MyModel` as a `Student`. Students belong to different campuses. Student A from Campus 1 can have the same `Id` as Student A from Campus 2. The combination of `Student.Id` and `Student.Campus` is unique, and can be considered as primary key. But Django doesn't allow to use `Id` field name without setting `primary_key=True`. Using `Student.user_id` as a field name sounds stupid. Whereas, `Student.id` sounds perfect.

Comment: Again, I am trying to use `Id` as a field name without setting `primary_key=True`.